# Where can I find this HP modular keyboard or similar?

Tags: keyboard

I'm looking for an **HP USB 104-Key Modular Keyboard with Detachable Number Pad** (model number is DT530A, I believe), shown at [this online store](http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=KU-0412), where it's quite cheap but is sadly sold out. I've searched for hours on Google, and I've found several - the problem is they're Spanish or Greek keyboards but I need one in English (US keys preferred)! I would also be happy with a keyboard which is not exactly this but is similar, either with a detachable keypad or with no keypad at all, as long as the keyboard key layout and positioning is the same as on a standard keyboard. Can you help me find such a keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

- Found it at [Server Parts
  Warehouse](http://www.serverpartswarehouse.com/DT530AHPHP-KB-Modular-USRefurbished-P436392.aspx) - 5 units available
  Price:    $149.00
- As far as "a keyboard
  which is not exactly this but is
  similar" I got nothing...

Took Some Work Too...

Answer (score 1):

I think you might enjoy the [Sidewinder X6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DWI4FM). If you want a wireless solution, logitech has [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000AY0IT4).